Exception mapping string column value in Entity Framework Core 8 to an enum
I have an entity model which has a property of an enum type, and the values from the database column are strings.
I get this exception when reading data from DbContext:

Requested value 'PointSync' was not found.

This happens when the db value doesn't exist in the Enum(ConfigurationType). The database is not dedicated exclusively to my project. It is a large database of a legacy application and from time to time it happens that a new value is inserted by the other application. I used the enum to keep the code clean (the exception is actually alerting us about the change), but I want to receive something like 'UnknownConfig' instead of getting a cast exception.
What is the proper way to handle this?
This is my model class:
public class Configuration
{
    public int ConfigurationId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public ConfigurationType Type { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public DateTime LastChange { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public bool Active { get; set; }
}

The enum looks like this:
public enum ConfigurationType
{   
    Search,
    Mailing,   
}

this snippet shows the err. https://onecompiler.com/csharp/42zjjqhp5
so far i have read that i can define conversions in EF modelBuilder. i haven't tried it yet.

What I think you are looking for is something like this: DefaultValue
To set the default value of the ENUM. Hope this helps

default value is for the case of not having a value. In my case i have a string value, but it doesn't match with any enum member.
as i see casting to an enum is by either the integer index or the string comparison. So what is the way to customize this? smth like an extention or attribute?

Have you tried to pass the first member of your enum as UnknownConfig, I believe the enum will check and use the first one as default.

yes i tried to have the first member as None. but it doesnt work since "None" is a word and doesnt match with any unexpected value that comes from database.
please pay attention that there is no integer number here. values are string (same words as ConfigurationType members).
